# Second-pass rendering in Metal -- is it this easy?

Tags: swift, metal

I'm new to Metal and I'm baffled...

I have a set of vertices which I'm "tiling" out from a master texture.  I'm using both a vertex shader and a fragment sampling shader to do this.

I wanted to overlay the first drawing pass with an additional drawing pass using a different texture.  I was getting all stressed out about having to do Load/Store actions and such.  Alas, no -- below is what I did in my render loop in Swift.  I should say that the amount of drawing in the overlay obliterates less than 5% of that in the first pass.

This works.  **Is it really just this easy?**

I just have this nagging feeling that I'm missing something. On the other hand, I may have been under the mistaken impression that one only gets one chance in a render loop, say, to set the vertex buffer of the render encoder.

```html
let renderEncoder : MTLRenderCommandEncoder = (commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor!))!
renderEncoder.label = "MyRenderEncoder"

renderEncoder.setViewport(MTLViewport.init(originX: 0.0, originY: 0.0, width:  Double(self.drawableSize.width), height: Double(self.drawableSize.height), znear: -1.0, zfar: 1.0))
renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self.pipelineState)

// draw main content
let vertices = ...
let vCount = vertices?.count
let vSize = vCount!*MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertices?[0])
let mBuff = self.device!.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices!, length: vSize, options: [])
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(mBuff, offset: 0, at: 0)
renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&self.viewportSize, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self.viewportSize), at: 1)
renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(inputTexture, at: 0)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: MTLPrimitiveType.triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vCount!)

// draw overlaying content
let vertices2 = ...
let vCount2 = vertices2?.count
let vSize2 = vCount2!*MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertices2?[0])
let mBuff2 = self.device!.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices2!, length: vSize2, options: [])
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(mBuff2, offset: 0, at: 0)
renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&self.viewportSize, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self.viewportSize), at: 1)
renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(inputTexture2, at: 0)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: MTLPrimitiveType.triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vCount2!)

// done drawing
renderEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer?.present(view.currentDrawable!)
commandBuffer?.commit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear which part you were worried about, but, yes, that works. You can change any of the properties of a render command encoder for which there's a "set" method at any point and do some more drawing. You are **not** limited to a single draw per encoder, nor even a single draw configuration. The only things which are fixed for the lifetime of the render command encoder are the properties described by the render pass descriptor you use to create it.

You can even change which render pipeline state is used. However, remember that the render pass descriptor is fixed and the render pipeline state's attachment pixel formats must match the render pass descriptor's attachment textures.

Of course, if you need to, you can use multiple command encoders and it's really not hard to set up the load and store actions.